# Can't access USB external hard drive puggled into my box with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, hard-drive, samba, 20.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. I have an external USB hard drive plugged into my box.

Until version 18.04, I did `smb://192.168.1.1/nameofmydrive` to access it. 
This does not seem possible with Ubuntu 20.04.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: What is "your box"? And what is `192.168.1.1`?

Comment: My box is zyxel VMG8823-B50B and 192.168.1.1 is the IP of my modem

Comment: Why it doesn't seem possible? Any errors? Is samba installed?

Comment: i have a message error. Samba is installed yes. Work with my computer 18.04

Answer (score 3):

I could find the answer: SMB1 is disabled by default.

To re-activate it:

Add code in the `[global]` section of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:
to paste just below the line `[global]`

```
client min protocol = CORE
```